# Seeking a launcher app able to properly manage files stored in iCloud

Tags: icloud, finder, alfred, quicksilver, launchbar

I have been evaluating several "launcher" apps, including LaunchBar, QuickSilver, Raycast, and Alfred.

As far as I can tell, none of them seems fully aware of iCloud-managed files that are currently offline. They tend to behave as if these files did not exist. In the Finder, instead, they are listed with the little cloud icon to indicate their status and it is possible to Download them at will.

Am I missing something? Is this functionality overlooked by third-party developers or is it inherently difficult to implement?

Comment: There is Raycast which has no problem of finding files which due to storage optimization are not actually stored in local machine. But this doesn't mean that finding and trying to open such a file triggers download.  While trying to open found file which has no local copy in some cases results in pop-up window with message  that file doesn't exist (photos/videos) in other cases opens file's metadata (text files).

Comment: @AivarPaalberg, you are partially correct about Raycast's behavior. The File Search command will indeed detect currently offline files when searched by name. However, strangely enough, if you apply the "Enclosing Folder" action on the found file, offline files are NOT shown (including the one you just found!). Similarly, the "Manage Files" command allows you to navigate folders but does NOT show offline files in them.

Comment: I think that I am not partially but wholly correct :-). The question was about ability to find offline files. Raycast does find those. "Enclosing Folder" action is introduced in comment, not in the question. I just mention that "Show in Finder" action opens Finder window in folder with found file selected and from there it is possible to open/download the the file (cmd+o for example)

Comment: @AivarPaalberg, let me rephrase. Raycast is _partially aware_ of offline files, as they can be found via FS but are not shown in folders (either by triggering the Enclosing Folder action or via the Manage Files command). I have added Raycast to the list of tested launchers and edited the text accordingly. Thanks for your input! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can at least explain what *is* possible with Quicksilver since I added the iCloud features.

- It will look for things in `~/Library/Mobile Documents` and try to add them to the catalog (if you have the iCloud Documents preset enabled).
- If you select an app and hit `→` or `/`, you will see that app’s iCloud documents, as well as any recent documents for the app.

But unfortunately that only includes files that exist on your local machine. I don’t think Apple allows apps to see files in iCloud other than the ones that belong to that app.

Comment: If the disk has full disk access they can see all iCloud files